# Why does Doctrine SQLite ignores authentication configuration?

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine

It seems like setting username and password in SQLite Doctrine `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` **does not create a username/password protected  sqlite database**.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        charset:  UTF8
        url: '%DATABASE_URL%'
        user:     'foo'
        password: 'bar'
```

It seems like the parameters username and password are ignored?

Comment: correct, they are ignored because in most cases, sqlite is not even compiled with user auth support. https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt . sqlite is meant to provide a simple database (actually not that simple, but easy to use) for embedded use or local file system use, where user management would overcomplicate things and slow it down. it also doesn't behave very nicely when faced with lots of simultaneous writes (can lock up). so I would advise against sqlite for a production write-enabled web service ...https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Doctrine's [docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url) you'll find this:

> For connecting to an SQLite database, the authority portion of the URL is obviously irrelevant and thus can be omitted. The path part of the URL is, like for all other drivers, stripped of its leading slash, resulting in a relative file name for the database:
>
> `sqlite:///somedb.sqlite`
>
> This would access somedb.sqlite in the current working directory and is identical to the following:
>
> `sqlite://ignored:ignored@ignored:1234/somedb.sqlite`

But the truth is that the username and password are probably being ignored by sqlite directly, and not by Doctrine.

If you check the `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver::connect()`, you'll find that [the parameters are passed to PDO](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.5/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOSqlite/Driver.php#L46).

But unless [you compiled your installed sqlite to add authentication support](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt), it won't have any use for user and password parameters, and will be ignored happily.

Using sqlite with authenticated users is very, very rarely a good idea; and if your use case requires them you'll likely be best served with a traditional DB server.